# iMessage and FaceTime account wrong

Tags: ipad

After my recent software update my iMessage and FaceTime account changed to my husbands on my iPad.  How do I change it back to mine?

Answer (score 1):

That is a very generic question to ask in this community. Please try following this tutorial http://osxdaily.com/2014/08/01/change-apple-id-ios/ to sign out of your husband's iCloud account completely (i.e. iCloud, iTunes etc), and be sure to sign in with your own.

If you remove his login information by logging him out and using your credentials instead, there shouldn't be any reason why the problem should persist.

Good Luck, let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the account to yours right away.

Settings -> Messages -> Send & Receive -> Make sure that your email is checked (or add it) under "you can be reached by imessage at" , and then delete the other email. Keep the phone number.

Settings -> Facetime -> Make sure that your email is checked (or add it) "you can be reached by Facetime at", and then delete the other email. Keep the phone number.

If everything there looks good, then go to the main settings page and look for a name above Airplane mode and Wifi. Click that name, make sure the email at the top of the page is correct and then go to iTunes and App Store and make sure that Apple ID email is also correct.